# Capture all Regex matches into a vector

Tags: regex, rust

I'd like to capture all the numbers in a string and return a vector of integers, something like this (the result can be an empty vector):

```
fn str_strip_numbers(s: &str) -> Vec<isize> {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

A Python prototype:

```
def str_strip_numbers(s):
    """
    Returns a vector of integer numbers
    embedded in a string argument.
    """
    return [int(x) for x in re.compile('\d+').findall(s)]
```

For `"alfa"` the result is `[]`, for `"42by4"` it is `[42, 4]`.

What is the idiomatic way to get it in Rust?

UPD:

```
fn str_strip_numbers(s: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    lazy_static! {
        static ref RE: Regex = Regex::new(r"\d+").unwrap();
    }
    RE.captures(s).and_then(|cap| {cap})
}
```

I tried something like this, which is grossly wrong on more than one count. What would be the right approach?

Comment: Note: `isize` is NOT a number it's a *cough* relative size *cough*, you should not use it in the context of "number" use `i64` if you want

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want all of the matches then you probably want to use `find_iter()`, which gives you an iterator over all of the matches. Then you'll need to convert the string matches into integers, and finally collect the results into a vector.

```
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use regex::Regex;

fn str_strip_numbers(s: &str) -> Vec<i64> {
    lazy_static! {
        static ref RE: Regex = Regex::new(r"\d+").unwrap();
    }
    // iterate over all matches
    RE.find_iter(s)
        // try to parse the string matches as i64 (inferred from fn type signature)
        // and filter out the matches that can't be parsed (e.g. if there are too many digits to store in an i64).
        .filter_map(|digits| digits.as_str().parse().ok())
        // collect the results in to a Vec<i64> (inferred from fn type signature)
        .collect()
}
```